# Plotting multiple histograms of Correlations

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

So I need to create a plots (`ggplot`) of multiple histograms for each cross sectional units.

Lets say that we have a data.frame of correlation of all independent variables (to dependent variable) and we need to visualize as histogram, multiple histograms, using probably `facet_wrap` or similar.

I know how to perform it with one variable:
`ggplot(DATA, aes(A)) + geom_histogram()` but I would like to see all variables (A, B, C, ...) in one single plot NOT mechanically creating all plot and then using `grid.arrange` is preferred for me since I we can have a datasets with even more of variables.

sample dataset:

```
unit <- c(1:100)
A <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
B <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
C <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
D <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
E <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
F <- c(runif(100,-1,1))

DATA <- data.frame(unit, A, B, C, D, E, F)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to get your data into long format (using e.g. `pivot_longer` from tidyr) and then you can `facet_wrap`:

```r
unit <- c(1:100)
A <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
B <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
C <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
D <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
E <- c(runif(100,-1,1))
F <- c(runif(100,-1,1))

library(tidyverse)

data.frame(unit, A, B, C, D, E, F) %>%
  pivot_longer(-unit) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~name)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>